# Zebra TLP 2844 printer refusing to print too many lines

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, epl

I'm trying to print some vouchers with variable length on continuous paper. The problem is that the printer refuses to print anything beyond around 2300 points (approximately 26 cm or 10.4 inches) and just pretends it's not there. Very light code triggers the problem, so it's not a buffer issue. The printer also manages to read the "print" command and all the lines are formatted exactly the same, so it's not a formatting issue either. Here's a not quite minimal, but almost, example of code that illustrates my point:

```
N //clear buffer
Q10,0 //set paper to continuous mode with 10 points between documents
R0,0 //set reference point 
ZT //print from top to bottom 
A100,50,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 50"
A100,100,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 100"
A100,150,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 150"
A100,200,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 200"
A100,250,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 250"
A100,300,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 300"
A100,350,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 350"
A100,400,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 400"
A100,450,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 450"
A100,500,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 500"
A100,550,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 550"
A100,600,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 600"
A100,650,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 650"
A100,700,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 700"
A100,750,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 750"
A100,800,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 800"
A100,850,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 850"
A100,900,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 900"
A100,950,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 950"
A100,1000,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1000"
A100,1050,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1050"
A100,1100,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1100"
A100,1150,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1150"
A100,1200,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1200"
A100,1250,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1250"
A100,1300,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1300"
A100,1350,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1350"
A100,1400,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1400"
A100,1450,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1450"
A100,1500,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1500"
A100,1550,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1550"
A100,1600,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1600"
A100,1650,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1650"
A100,1700,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1700"
A100,1750,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1750"
A100,1800,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1800"
A100,1850,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1850"
A100,1900,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1900"
A100,1950,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 1950"
A100,2000,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2000"
A100,2050,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2050"
A100,2100,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2100"
A100,2150,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2150"
A100,2200,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2200"
A100,2250,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2250"
A100,2300,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2300"
A100,2350,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2350"
A100,2400,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2400"
A100,2450,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2450"
A100,2500,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2500"
A100,2550,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2550"
A100,2600,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2600"
A100,2650,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2650"
A100,2700,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2700"
A100,2750,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2750"
A100,2800,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2800"
A100,2850,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2850"
A100,2900,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2900"
A100,2950,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 2950"
A100,3000,0,1,1,2,N,"ASDFQWERTY 3000"
P1
```

There's a blank line before the first "N", as specified in the EPL2 manual (http://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/printer/epl2-pm-en.pdf). I also don't include comments when sending the commands to the printer. However, this only prints until the line that says "ASDFQWERTY 2300" and ignores everything beyond that. Any help is greately appreciated.

Comment: i don't understand the hate on this question, it's completely valid, and working with this printers is hell

Comment: It's somehow still getting downvotes. My guess is that the people at zebra are conspiring with the illuminati against me and my question. Curse you, zebra!

Comment: @Jonathan 5 years later and yes, hell indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering myself from a support email I got from the company. This printer model is limited to 11 inches, so in the end I had to split the document onto several requests.